# Passing arguments from client to a task when a task is picked from FTP location instead of peer class loading in Ignite

Tags: java, distributed-computing, ignite

Instead of using peer class loading approach, I am using jar based approach in which I am putting my task definition at an FTP location and Ignite cluster polls FTP location to fetch the task class definition. In this approach, I want to pass some arguments to my task class from client. Is there any way in Ignite which can be utilized to do so?

```
igniteCompute.execute(taskName :: String)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/**
 * Executes given task within the cluster group. For step-by-step explanation of task execution process
 * refer to {@link ComputeTask} documentation.
 * <p>
 * If task for given name has not been deployed yet, then {@code taskName} will be
 * used as task class name to auto-deploy the task (see {@link #localDeployTask(Class, ClassLoader)} method).
 *
 * @param taskName Name of the task to execute.
 * @param arg Optional argument of task execution, can be {@code null}.
 * @return Task result.
 * @throws IgniteException If task failed.
 * @see ComputeTask for information about task execution.
 */
@IgniteAsyncSupported
public <T, R> R execute(String taskName, @Nullable T arg) throws IgniteException;
```

If you have more than one arg, use IgnitePair or an array as `T arg`.

Comment: Can you help me with how to access those arguments in the Compute task that is defined at a FTP location?

Comment: I think you will get it as 2nd argument of `org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeTask#map`